# Is possible to dynamic path in php files for assets in webpack wordpress development?

Tags: wordpress, webpack, path

I have a theme wordpress development folder (*theme/resources/assets*) for development and *theme/assets* for production. When I create `header.php` and add:

```
img src=”?php echo get_template_directory_uri();
?>/assets/images/code.png”
```

In development mode, images don't show up. It works only after build. In dev mode, the path must be */resources/assets/images/code.png*

How I can fix that? How I can dynamically change paths in Wordpress PHP files? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should fix the code from

```
img src=”?php echo get_template_directory_uri();
?>/assets/images/code.png”
```

To:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/images/code.png" />
```

For detecting the environment, you may use the built-in [`WP_DEBUG` constant](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/setting-up-a-development-environment/#wp_debug) and adjust the path as necessary:

```
<img src="<?php
  echo get_template_directory_uri() . (WP_DEBUG ? '/resources' : '');
?>/assets/images/code.png" />
```

Comment: This is great! Thank You!

Comment: Thats wrong on many levels, you can't assume environment and build by detecting the WP_DEBUG constant. Much better and safer would be defining WP_ENV or similar constant inside particular environment config. Additionally it should be extracted into some assets path helper otherwise you would have to repeat that code for each image on the page

Comment: @Owi an even better approach would be to have a `get_template_directory_uri()` alternative/override which would detect the environment and adjust according to whatever config associated to that environment. This would be beyond the scope of this question though and trying to keep it simple, this is not intrinsically wrong and it serves the purpose of rapidly changing between 2 basic environments.

Comment: It is unfortunately wrong as it assumes WP_DEBUG true => development, otherwise production. 
And no - get template_directory_uri stays the same in both scenarios.

Comment: @Owi concerns about WP architecture are fine when you are releasing an official theme or placing the code in Github for example. Most developers just want to get things done for their clients...

Comment: And you would do it wrong. Because if you would need to investigate the issue on production by turning WP_DEBUG to true and logging to file you are going to lose all images and assets enqueued by your method.

With all due respect - this is simply wrong advice. Period.

Comment: @Owi I did not attempt to provide an advice with my answer, just a simple&quick solution to the problem. Your comments are providing the advice though: creating a configs structure and specific constants to handle different environments. So if you have the time to provide that advice in an answer for this particular problem, I believe that would be better than trying to argue several points in a comment section... BTW, images are never lost, all the references would just be replaced, allowing the person to remember to turn off WP_DEBUG at the end of "debugging" in production.

Comment: @CPHPython By losing I meant having wrong references to images. So for the time of the debugging which could last even hours or days (depending what would you like to log) the images/assets references will be broken which is unacceptable for most of the projects.

I agree though that this is stupid to argue over it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use site URL to check whether it's production or development site and return assets URL based on that:

```
<?php

$site_url = get_site_url();
if($site_url == 'http://http://stage.example.com'){
    // Staging site assets url
    $assets_url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/resources/assets';
}else{
    // Live site assets url
    $assets_url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets';
}

?>

<img src="<?php echo $assets_url; ?>/images/code.png" />
```

Same code can be used in different ways by changing the condition, if you have a better way to compare instead of site URL you can change the if statement and the ourput would be the same.